# Run function after Jcrop has finished loading (solution)

Tags: jquery, callback, onload, jcrop

This is not a question, just a tip after trying to get this to work myself. Maybe people know about it already but I found no documentation of it (on the Jcrop site or elsewhere).

This is actually just an undocumented feature, looking at the source code for Jcrop I noticed that it accepted a function as a second argument after the settings, which gets called after Jcrop has finished loading. So just enter your function there and presto!

```
  $('#imagetocrop')
    .Jcrop(
      {
        /* settings go here */
      },
      function() { alert('Jcrop has finished loading!) });
```

Note: The settings object is NOT optional in this case. the callback only works as a second argument. You can send an empty settings object {  } and it works just fine, but why you'd need a callback for such a simple Jcrop function is beyond me...

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#imagetocrop').Jcrop(
   {
     /* settings go here */
   },
   function() 
   { 
     alert('Jcrop has finished loading!) 
   });
```

Comment: @Jan Just moving it to the answer column. I tagged it as 'community wiki' so as not to take credit, and I just upvoted your original content.

Comment: Figured as much, was nice to be able to close the "question" too. Thanks mate! :)